# Transaction Control across multiple JVMs

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, transactions, jms

I have what seems to be a standard java problem: multiple database transactions, in Oracle, that need to all be committed or none. This is complicated by the fact that each process is in a seperate JVM.

The modules are connected by JMS queues in a pipeline configuration. The idea is that a series of messages can be passed through the pipeline, and when all the processing has finished a message can be sent from a coordinating module to cause all the transactions to commit.

Is it possible, with any sensible level of robustness, to synchronise commits across the multiple JVMs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there are multiple participants in a transaction, you need some two-phase commit protocol, like [XA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X/Open_XA).

When using JMS, you have an option to use [JMS transactions](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2002/jw-0315-jms.html).

And [here](http://activemq.apache.org/should-i-use-xa.html) is a comparison of the two options.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in reading [A brief history of Consensus, 2PC and Transaction Commit.](http://betathoughts.blogspot.com/2007/06/brief-history-of-consensus-2pc-and.html)